# Changing Iframe's src with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to change iframe's src attribute with jQuery. But this code isnt working. Even the alert doesnt show up.

**JS:**

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function loadIframe(url) {

  var $iframe = $('#' + <%=iPage.ClientID%>);//Also tried $('#<%=iPage.ClientID%>')
    if ( $iframe.length ) {
       $iframe.attr('src',url);   
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

**ASPX:**

```
<li>
  <asp:LinkButton id="link1" runat="server" OnClientClick="loadIframe( 
   'www.asd1234.com')" Text="Test"></asp:LinkButton>
</li>
<asp:updatepanel...>
  //.....
  <iframe id="iPage" runat="server"></iframe>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Comment: Take the function OUT of the document ready. And you'll want to have a `return false;` after the function call to cancel the links default action

Comment: I can see the alert, when the function is outside document ready. But the link click isnt working. I also tried with no return values

Comment: "Isn't working" is not exactly, helpful. What is it NOT doing that you think it should?

Comment: No Errors. Clicking on the link is supposed to load gogle in the iframe. And it isnt.

Comment: @Ruby, You can't load google in iframe. As Google is sends an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

Comment: Was just about to say the same thing @Satpal.  Google blocks itself from being used in iFrames on purpose, so if you're using them as an example, use a different site... but if you're actually wanting to use Google, then you can't

Comment: I have updated the query. Plz have a look. It isnt even saying page not found error.

Comment: @Ruby, Use `'<%= iPage.ClientID %>'` As I have mentioned in Answer

Comment: You've missed the `=` from the inline block that @Satpal rightly suggests

Comment: sorry was a typo here. but i didnt.

Comment: Make it `"#<%=iPage.ClientID%>"` instead... always good to check the **rendered** HTML

Answer (score 0):

As you are using

```
<iframe id="iPage" runat="server"></iframe>
```

You need to use [**Control.ClientID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    id="link1" 
    runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="loadIframe('<%= iPage.ClientID %>', 'www.google.com')" 
    Text="Test"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Also move function out of the document ready handler.

Comment: Are you sure inline code is valid in a server side control attribute?

Comment: I guess it is, cause when I put an alert in the JS, it popped. I dont know how to debug this. Its like the function isnt accepting these args or not recognizing.

Comment: The alert migt have worked, but I suspect that the string that was passed was actually ` <%= iPage.ClientID %>` rather than the actual ClientId of the control

Comment: The issues with the linkbutton. It's workingif i use <a></a>. Guess, I'll stop with this for now. Thank you..

Comment: @Ruby, I missed it you need to use return with client function call. Just try `OnClientClick="return loadIframe('<%= iPage.ClientID %>', 'www.google.com')" `